# Declare 'Array' of urls

Tags: java, xml, arrays, parsing, url

I am trying to read a set of urls froma file and parse xml file on each url (each one is basically links of xml files). Is there a way to declare an 'Array' of urls. I have to recursively pass all the urls to the sax parser. Any way of doing this? I am pretty new to java.

Comment: Could you post some examples of what you are trying to do? Is not very clear from your question.

Comment: have you try to store it in an ArrayList<String>?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your URLs are `String` objects, then this is the way to go.

```
String[] urls = new String[10]; // Initialize as per your needs.
```

Or else, `ArrayList` is better.

```
List<String> urls = new ArrayList<String>(); // Initialize as per your needs.
```

In case you've `URL` object itself, then replace `String` by `URL` in the above 2 scenarios.